# Correct encoding when putting C# strings into javascript strings in asp.net-mvc views

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, encoding

I have an asp.net-mvc view and I am generating a javascript array like this from my view model:

```
 var jsDict = new Array();
 <% foreach (var myEvent in Model.MyEvents) { %>
      jsDict['<%=myEvent.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>'] = '<%=myEvent.Title %>';
 <% } %>
```

The issue is that in some cases

```
 myEvent.Title
```

has an apostrophe in it so it breaks the string.

For example

```
jsDict['2015-01-01'] = 'Test is my 'first' test';
```

what is the correct way to escape around the word first above to make this a valid array.

I tried to change it to double quotes instead of apostrophes

```
 jsDict["2015-01-01"] = "Test is my 'first' test";
```

which seems to work but I have a fear that some of the event Titles would have a double quote it in so I want a solution that works for both apostrophe and double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the apostrophes as `\'`, and also escape backslashes as `\\`:

```
jsDict['<%=myEvent.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>'] = '<%=myEvent.Title.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("'", "\\'") %>';
```

If the string can contain control characters, you need to replace them too, for example adding `.Replace("\n", "\\n")`.